# Object to XML String - Object's property is not included in XML string

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am converting the following ListingRequest object to a XML string. However, the "Pickup" property of class ListingRequest  and the Type property of class ShippingOption is not being included in the XML string.

Code:

```
  ListingRequest s = new ListingRequest()
        {
            Pickup = PickupOptions.Allow,
            Category = "0124-0126-4592-",
            Title = "Cricket Bat",
            Description = new string[] { "This is a cricket bat", "Bat." },
            StartPrice = 20,
            BuyNowPrice = 20,
            Duration = ListingDuration.Five,
            ShippingOptions =
            new ShippingOption[]{new ShippingOption {Type = ShippingType.Free,
            Price = 77,
            Method = "Ruler delivery"}}
        };

            string xml = SerializeToString(s);
```

NOTE: The `Pickup` property of ListingRequest Object and the `Type` property of ShippingOption object is not included in the XML string.

**The ListingRequest and shipping option object can be found in the schema can be found** [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2caJPpRWlGSdTFZMWZ6dFhUMzA/edit).

And here is the `SerializeToString()` method

```
 public static string SerializeToString(object obj)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);

                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: please provide the  ListingRequest class,probably something to do with attributes...

Comment: the listing request class is in the schema I've provided the link to the schema file :)

Comment: You can add the schema file to console application and run the code above to check the output for your self.

Comment: You never use `ship` anywhere in your code. Do you expect it to appear magically in xml string?

Comment: oops I left that out, even if i add the shipping option to the listingrequest the "Type" property doesn't appear in the xml string. I have updated the code in the question. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Still cant find the issue.. this is weird and frustration.

Comment: Can you paste in the class definitions?